# how to pass data from broad cast receiver to main activity

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I registered a broad cast receiver in a separate file from the main activity, and based on the received notifications in the broad cast receiver, i want to perform some action in the main activity.

my question is, what is the recommended way to pass the notifications from the broad cast receiver to the main activity? should make a public method inside each Action iam registered for in the broad cast receiver file? or should use an interface that will be implemented in the main activity.

note: the broad cast reciever is registered for 7 actions

Comment: use Interface to implement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an Interface and let your Main activity Implement it,this helps in Polymorphism Pass in your MainActivity object as the Interface to the BroadcastListener File and call the appropriate methods in the interface based on the actions.( Since you are mentioning to either have public methods i believe you will have the reference to the MainActivity object). Implement it more like the Observer Pattern.

```
//BroadcastObserver.java
public interface BroadcastObserver {
    //methods methods 
   public void foo();
}

//MainActivity.java
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements BroadcastObserver{
 @Override
 public void foo(){

 }

}

public class MyClass {
  BroadcastObserver static observer;  // this should be set to by passing your MainActivity object, may be at the time when you initiate your MyClass object
  public static class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
     Toast.makeText(context, "!!!!.",
     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     if(someaction){
         observer.foo();
     }
  }


}
```

Comment: should i make the interfaace static?

Comment: no do not create it as an internal Interface. I will update with more code.

Comment: i have mostly followed the implementation based on your question.

Comment: i forgot to ask about how to initalise the "observer" object in your code, becasue if i run your code i will receive NPE

Comment: yes you will have to pass your MainActivity object when creating MyClass object may be in the construtor MyClass(BroadcastObserver observer){this.observer = observer } and pass "this" from your main activity

Comment: I hope you were previously sending the reference of your MainActivity to your Class.

Comment: can u please modify the code, i passed reference of the mainactivtiy to the  broadcast receiver class to initiate the interface but i still receive the same error:android unable to instantiate receiver instantiationexception

Comment: change your BroadCast Reciever class to static, i have made some changes in the code though not tested.

Comment: i still receive the same error, and can u please tell me why do i need "MyClass", in my code i created the receiver as follows: public class BTReceiver extends BroadCastReceiver. and it cant be static

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88676/discussion-between-hars-and-user2121).